# Pybrain:Run Time Error

Tags: python, pybrain

I am trying to create a Neural Network using pybrain.
The following is my code.

Number of input neurons would be 2500.
Number of output neurons is 212.
Number of hidden neurons is (2500+212)/2 = 1356.

My Code :

```
#for training using the data set
#import built in json module for reading the binary list of lists
import json

#retrieve the input file
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
inputSet = json.load(f) 

#retrieve target file target file
f = open('target.txt', 'r')
targetSet = json.load(f)

#Width and height of character image
w,h = 50, 50

#import pybrain modules
from pybrain.structure.networks import FeedForwardNetwork
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.utilities import percentError
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure.modules import SoftmaxLayer
from pybrain.structure.modules import LinearLayer
from pybrain.structure.modules import SigmoidLayer
from pybrain.structure.modules import TanhLayer
from pybrain.structure.connections import FullConnection
from pybrain.tools.customxml.networkwriter import NetworkWriter
from pybrain.tools.customxml.networkreader import NetworkReader

#import matplotlib to plot the learning graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#setting up the network
#initialize the number of neurons for the various layers
inputNeurons = w * h #2500
outputNeurons = 212
hiddenNeurons = int((inputNeurons + outputNeurons) /2) #1356

net = buildNetwork(inputNeurons, hiddenNeurons, outputNeurons, bias = True, hiddenclass = SigmoidLayer)

#view a glimpse of NN structure
print net

#initialise dataset
ds = SupervisedDataSet(inputNeurons, outputNeurons)

#add training data to network
for i in range(0,212):
    ds.addSample(inputSet[i], targetSet[i])

#print len(ds)

#initialize trainers
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, dataset=ds,  learningrate = 0.01, momentum = 0.5, verbose=True)

#startTraining
trainer.trainEpochs (100)

#store network in XML
NetworkWriter.writeToFile(net, 'trained.xml')
```

The problem is am running into the following error for every momentum value other than 0.9.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg\pybrain\supervised\trainers\backprop.py", line 97
    error += 0.5 * sum(outerr ** 2)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pybrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg\pybrain\structure\modules\sigmoidlayer.py", line 14
    inerr[:] = outbuf * (1 - outbuf) * outerr
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

I have searched around a lot and am not able to find a concrete solution to this.

I can see it has to do something with numpy not handling large float numbers but am really not sure how I can go about fixing it.

Any suggestions would be welcome.